# how to set assign different variables to different environments in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

Hello i have this json object

......

```
products: docs.map(doc =>{
        return {
          name: doc.name,
          price: doc.price,
          id: doc._id,
          productImage: doc.productImage,
          request:{

            type: 'GET',
            url: 'localhost:3000/products/'+ doc.id 
          }
        }
      })
```

This works fine on development, But on production, the hardcoded URL does not work on Heroku of course.

so how can I make the `url: 'localhost:3000/products/'+ doc.id` to read `url: 'https://myherokuapp.com/products/'+ doc.id` while on heroku.

Thanks

Comment: Is this a serverside script?

Answer (score 0):

you can use a config.js file to store your two defferent urls and toggle them when deploying using a simple edit. but there is more elegant way use morgan moddleware to toggle between dev and prodcution environments

[here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan)